# Recursive vs iterative to get more performance

Tags: performance, recursion, iteration, knapsack-problem

In terms of performance which approach is better for the knapsack problem: iterative, or recursive?

Limited to `1 sec` I need to sort out which of 40 items should the knapsack be filled with to get the most valuable items, a typical knapsack problem.

I know that if I do a brute force to determine which items to select I get `2^41 - 1` subproblems to solve, so it is very unthoughtful to use this solution, but is it a way to cut down the unneeded branches and make it as efficient as the iterative form?

On the other hand if the weight is very big, the matrix would be enormous and also as inefficient as the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

With that kind of problem, asking "iterative or recursive" doesn't get you anywhere. What you need to do is write code, measure what it is doing, start understanding what takes time and why, and as your understanding of the problem grows, you'll find more effective ways of attacking the problem.

The problem is NP-complete which means that there are at least pathological cases that cannot be solved quickly. But in practice, many problems can be solved quickly. You want to pick items with high value/weight ratio, and pick items that fill the rucksack well. And you don't want to try all possibilities, you want to find one good solution and with the help of that good solution be able to reject large sets of possibilities quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a typical knapsack problem, isn't it possible to use Dynamic Programming to use the previous results in an iterative way as they're stored in a matrix and using a recursive formula to evaluate the new values?